# HTML5 canvas : setting background image

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a `canvas` and am setting a background image to the canvas, using thymeleaf `th:style` tag , like this.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" th:style="'background: url('+@{backgroundImageUrl}+') no-repeat center center;'" ></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
</div>
```

The above code renders the canvas in its default size, cropping the background image. Since the `backgroundImageUrl` loads images of various size dynamically, I can't set height and width to the canvas.

How do I set the width and height to the canvas, so that

1. The canvas should fit in the `span6` div, without cropping the background image, when background image size is very large
2. The canvas should fit in the `span6` div and background image should aligned center, when background image size is very small

Comment: width:100% height:.....

Comment: width:100% causes to overflow the background image from `span6` div

Comment: set up a jsfiddle ill have a look

Comment: Check jsfiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/jmoe9kq1/2/

Comment: Did you consider to assign the background image to the div which contains the canvas?